# Span Overlay On Image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to show an overlay on an image on hover. Here is a part of my code:

```
        <div class="wrapper-showcase">
            <div class="first">
                <img src="showcase-1.png" />
                <span class="overlay"></span>
            </div>
            ...
        </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
                .wrapper-showcase div.first img {
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    z-index: -100;
                }

                .wrapper-showcase div.first span {
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
                    display: inline-block;
                    left: 0;
                    top: -50%;
                    z-index: 100;
                }
```

The Image is stretching to fill the parent div, but the span which I want to display just doesn't show up. It is showing up below the said image. Is there any way I can overlay them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/87jrnp0w/)
I added:

```
.first{
position:relative;
}
```

and I changed the span

```
.wrapper-showcase div.first span {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    display: inline-block;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color:moccasin;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

(I also added `background-color:moccasin` so you can see what happens)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks. Although I managed to do this by introducing the images as a CSS Background and then overlaying the translucent span on top. Thanks.